# Which Nim library for data visualization has a HTML output?

Tags: html, json, dataframe, nim-lang, jester

I am new to the Nim language.

To visualize JSON outputs, what would be the best library?
Is there any good library for visualizing outputs of data frames and if possible, not only in the browser?

I am trying to find an equivalent to the Python `Pandas` library which has a `to_html()` method.
I tried `Jester` but can't find out how to convert a JSON output to an HTML table.

The only equivalent library that I could find on Google was NimData, which has a `to_html` method like Pandas. This method does not support JSON.

I am not using Python Pandas to get familiar with the Nim language.

Comment: Maybe this: https://scinim.github.io/getting-started/data_viz/plotting_data.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Datamancer](https://github.com/SciNim/Datamancer).
It has a `df.toHtml` output method.

You can use `showBrowser` to write the DataFrame in an HTML file and show it in your default browser.

Based on the documentation, I wrote a small code snippet as an example:

```
import datamancer

let s1: seq[int] = @[22, 54, 34]
let s2: seq[float] = @[1.87, 1.75, 1.78]
let s3: seq[string] = @["Mike", "Laura", "Sue"]
let df = toDf({ "Age": s1,
                "Height": s2,
                "Name": s3 })
echo df.toHtml()
```

which outputs:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
<tr><th> Index </th><th> Age <br><br> int </th><th> Height <br><br> float </th><th> Name <br><br> string </th></tr>
</thead><tbody><tr>
<td>0</td><td>22</td><td>1.87</td><td>Mike</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>1</td><td>54</td><td>1.75</td><td>Laura</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>2</td><td>34</td><td>1.78</td><td>Sue</td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

and in the browser:

```
showBrowser(df)
```

[image: output of showBrowser(df)]

If you have questions about the rendering algorithm, you can look up the code generation in the source file:
https://github.com/SciNim/Datamancer/blob/master/src/datamancer/io.nim#L766-L836

The documentation system currently has some issues and the `toHTML` proc does not appear in the generated docs.

I made this post from the answers of @Vindaar and @hugogranstrom (Github and Discord accounts).

Answer (score 0):

try [nim-plotly](https://github.com/SciNim/nim-plotly).

it does have a proc called [`save`](https://github.com/SciNim/nim-plotly/blob/35f634279f1f52bbadccf5d9bb9ad55a3c89ea53/src/plotly/plotly_display.nim#L157)